# Added dependency to pom.xml but keeps saying "package does not exist"

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I am working on patch: https://gist.github.com/ensonic/4deddeff42e80fc93685112689dbc91f
for this project: https://github.com/OpenRoberta/robertalab/

I've added the new dependency to the pom.xml and I run `mvn clean install`. This unexpectedly fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project OpenRobertaServer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/ensonic/projects/lego/robertalab/OpenRobertaServer/src/main/java/de/fhg/iais/roberta/main/ServerStarter.java:[9,45] package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ensonic/projects/lego/robertalab/OpenRobertaServer/src/main/java/de/fhg/iais/roberta/main/ServerStarter.java:[9,45] package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ensonic/projects/lego/robertalab/OpenRobertaServer/src/main/java/de/fhg/iais/roberta/main/ServerStarter.java:[115,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class GzipHandler
[ERROR] location: class de.fhg.iais.roberta.main.ServerStarter
[ERROR] /home/ensonic/projects/lego/robertalab/OpenRobertaServer/src/main/java/de/fhg/iais/roberta/main/ServerStarter.java:[115,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class GzipHandler
[ERROR] location: class de.fhg.iais.roberta.main.ServerStarter
[ERROR] /home/ensonic/projects/lego/robertalab/OpenRobertaServer/src/main/java/de/fhg/iais/roberta/main/ServerStarter.java:[118,32] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable myHandler
[ERROR] location: class de.fhg.iais.roberta.main.ServerStarter
```

I've looked at `mvn -e` or `mvn -X`, but neither have any info that I find helpful.

When it fails I can't find the jetty-servlets-9.2.5.v20141112.jar that would satisfy the dependency anywhere in the project tree. If I remove the modifications to the java code and build (which now passes) then the required jar is there:

```
$ find .. -name "jetty-servlets-9.2.5.v20141112.jar"
../OpenRobertaServer/target/resources/jetty-servlets-9.2.5.v20141112.jar
```

The pom.xml is using the maven-dependency-plugin, but as far as I see this is for the tests and the compile should work without it, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you something like:

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.9.v20160517</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you show the entire pom dependencies?

About the use of that class, from the official doc:

> The Jetty GzipHandler is a compression handler that you can apply to
>   any dynamic resource (servlet). It fixes many of the bugs in commonly
>   available compression filters: it works with asynchronous servlets; it
>   handles all ways to set content length. We have tested it with Jetty
>   continuations and suspending requests. Some user-agents might be
>   excluded from compression to avoid common browser bugs (yes, this
>   means IE!).
>
> The GzipHandler is added to the entire server by the
>   etc/jetty-gzip.xml file from the gzip.mod module. It may also be added
>   to individual contexts in a context xml file.

Link: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.8.v20160314/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/gzip/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: Don't use `<version>9.3.0.M1</version>`, that's an unstable beta/milestone build!  Use something recent and stable instead, such as `<version>9.3.9.v20160517</version>`

Comment: The whole pom is here https://github.com/OpenRoberta/robertalab/blob/master/OpenRobertaParent/pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself after some time. I used http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/ to look at the *exact* docs matching my version and while checking it, I learned that the jetty projects seems to have no notion of stable ABI. The methods and packages are renamed on an almost daily basis, often leaving deprecation comments pointing to api that itself got renamed again.
Very sad.

To conclude the maven setup was correct, but the api that I meant to use wes named differently.

Comment: Reminder: Jetty versioning is `{servlet_support_level}.{major_version}.{minor_version}`.  Meaning going from 9.0 to 9.1 is a [major version update](http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/jetty/).  The most common cause for heartburn here is the assumption that Jetty (started in 1995) has the same versioning scheme as everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't aware of that. Still especially around the gzip handler the api changed a lot and a lot of advice on the net how to use it would not work, but that's a different story.